# Need to read .dat file in scala ide

Tags: scala

Need to read .dat files (binary files) from local and write the output in console using scala IDE,

Is it required first convert .dat file to .txt/.csv file then we can read and apply if any transformation and again need to convert .txt/.csv to .dat

tried with some existing code
ref:http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-read-write-binary-files-in-scala-examples

still getting error ,Please share any suggestion

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .dat is just a name without much meaning attached.  what format is the file?  is it binary data or text?

Comment: it's a binary file

Comment: please edit your post to include your formatted code instead of leaving it in a comment.  It is too hard to read in a comment

Comment: You haven't posted your code or your current error. Your question makes no sense. There is no standard csv representation for binary data. I'm voting to close this question.